# how to create a temporary variable in the camel context for later use in the route

Tags: http-headers, apache-camel, cross-cutting-concerns

I have a route which interacts with 4 http endpoints. the first http endpoint is an authorization service from which i will get one authentication token. What i want is once i get the token from the authorization service i will pass the token to each further http service in the header. so how can i achieve that? is there any way of creating a temporary variable using the token value and if i can place it in the context then in any endpoint i can set it. 
or else i was thinking if i can invoke the authorization service once at application startup once and store the token somewhere and i can use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can store properties on your exchange object:

http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/Exchange.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)

For example in my "pipeline" I'm storing ID from DB for later use:

```
from("quartz2://myScheduler?cron=0+0+6,14,22+*+*+?")
   .to("sql:" + getNextID() + "?dataSource=#dataSource&outputType=SelectOne")
   .setProperty("NextID", simple("${body[id]}"))
```

Then, the *NextID* is accessible from exchange `exchange.getProperty("NextID")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [headers](http://camel.apache.org/header.html) or [properties](http://camel.apache.org/property.html)